# How to configure account locking for Sonatype Nexus UI?

Tags: security, user-interface, authentication, nexus3

How can we configure a maximum limit for login retry attempts for invalid credentials in the Sonatype Nexus repository manager UI (v 3.19.x) ?

[Sample User Interface screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuJzV.png)